# Is Dataset.rdd an action or transformation?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

one of the way to evaluate if a dataframe is empty or not is to do `df.rdd.isEmpty()`, however, I see `rdd at mycode.scala:123` in sparkUI executions. which makes me wonder if this rdd() function is actually an action is instead of a transformation.

I know that isEmpty() is an action, but I do see a separate stage where `isEmpty() at mycode.scala:234`, so I think they are different actions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rdd` is generated to represent a structured query in "RDD terms" so Spark can execute it. It is an RDD of JVM objects of your type `T`. If used incorrectly can cause memory problems since:

1. Transfers internally-managed optimized rows that live outside JVM to the memory space in JVM
2. Transforms the binary rows to your business objects (the JVM "true" representation)

The first will increase the JVM memory required for the computation while the latter is an extra transformation step.

For such a simple calculation where you count the number of rows, you'd rather stick to `count` as the optimized and fairly cheap computation (that can avoid copying objects and applying schema).

Internally, `Dataset` keeps rows in their `InternalRow`. That decreases JVM memory requirement for your Spark application. The RDD (from `rdd`) is computed to represent the Spark transformations that **are going to** be executed once a Spark action is executed.

Please note that executing `rdd` creates a RDD and does require some calculations too.

So, yes, `rdd` might be considered an action as it "executes" the query (i.e. the physical plan of the Dataset that sits behind), but in the end it just gives an `RDD` (so it can't be an action by definition since Spark actions return a non-RDD value).

As you can see in the [code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L2695-L2700):

```
  lazy val rdd: RDD[T] = {
    val objectType = exprEnc.deserializer.dataType
    val deserialized = CatalystSerde.deserialize[T](logicalPlan) // <-- HERE see explanation below
    sparkSession.sessionState.executePlan(deserialized).toRdd.mapPartitions { rows =>
      rows.map(_.get(0, objectType).asInstanceOf[T])
    }
  }
```

`rdd` is computed lazily and only once.

---

> one of the way to evaluate if a dataframe is empty or not is to do `df.rdd.isEmpty()`

I wonder where did you find it. I'd just [count](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@count():Long):

> **count(): Long** Returns the number of rows in the Dataset.

### toRdd Lazy Value

If you insist on going fairly low-level to check whether your Dataset is empty or not, I'd rather use `Dataset.queryExecution.toRdd` instead. That's almost like `rdd` without this extra copying and applying schema.

```
df.queryExecution.toRdd.isEmpty
```

Compare the following RDD lineages and think which may seem better.

```
val dataset = spark.range(5).withColumn("group", 'id % 2)
scala> dataset.rdd.toDebugString
res1: String =
(8) MapPartitionsRDD[8] at rdd at <console>:26 [] // <-- extra deserialization step
 |  MapPartitionsRDD[7] at rdd at <console>:26 []
 |  MapPartitionsRDD[6] at rdd at <console>:26 []
 |  MapPartitionsRDD[5] at rdd at <console>:26 []
 |  ParallelCollectionRDD[4] at rdd at <console>:26 []

// Compare with a more memory-optimized alternative
// Avoids copies and has no schema
scala> dataset.queryExecution.toRdd.toDebugString
res2: String =
(8) MapPartitionsRDD[11] at toRdd at <console>:26 []
|  MapPartitionsRDD[10] at toRdd at <console>:26 []
|  ParallelCollectionRDD[9] at toRdd at <console>:26 []
```

From Spark perspective, the transformations are fairly cheap since they don't cause any shuffles, but given the memory requirements change between the computation I'd use the latter (with `toRdd`).

### rdd Lazy Value

`rdd` represents the content of the `Dataset` as a (lazily-created) `RDD` with rows of the JVM type `T`.

```
rdd: RDD[T]
```

As you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L2695-L2701) (pasted above), requesting `rdd` in the end will trigger one extra computation just to get the RDD.

1. Creates a new logical plan to deserialize the Dataset’s logical plan, i.e. you get extra deserialization from internal binary row format that is managed outside JVM to its corresponding representation as JVM objects living **inside** JVM (think of GC that you should avoid at all cost)

Comment: thank you for those explanations, I do have another question, count() is also an action, and has to calculate all rows. while rdd.isEmpty() is doing just take(1), so it might be faster in this case right?

Comment: @linehrr added the new section on rdd. Let me know if you need anything else. Let's clear all the doubts! Happy Sparking! :)